# SSL Connection fails for Parse.Cloud.HTTPRequest call

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, connection, httprequest

I'm getting an SSL Connection failed error when I try to connection to an HTTPS endpoint using Parse.Cloud.HTTPRequest. My guess is that the CA that issued the SSL Certificate isn't trusted by the Parse Server. Is there a way to trust that particular CA/Certificate?

Comment: Is there any update on same. I am getting the same SSL error while calling the Parse.Cloud.HTTPRequest Call and I am not able to figure out any lead to fix this!